# Using one call to twitter and twitter count it as many

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm using [abrahm library](https://github.com/abraham/) to connect to twitter
and i'm using Search REST API in my PHP website , after every request to Twitter API i check the rate limit it decreasing by 50 , like if im requesting 50 times to The API
any help for that

this is my connecting method

```
$temp=$con->get('search/tweets', array('q' => $hash ,'count'=>100));
```

Comment: Which of those many twitter-related repositories do you exactly use?

Comment: When calling `$connection->get('application/rate_limit_status',array('resources'=>'search'));` I get the result as said before

Answer (score 1):

Note that with API version 1.1 Twitter changed the way, rate limiting works. As you are speaking of a general “rate limit”, I assume that you are still accessing the version 1.0 rate limit information.

I’d suggest you to read up on [the new rate limiting](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1) and the [actual limits](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1/limits). In your case, you should be able to make 180 searches per 15 minutes using the 1.1 [search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) interface. You can get the current status of your rate limits using the [application/rate_limit_status](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/application/rate_limit_status) interface, using `search` as its resource parameter.

Comment: No im using 1.1 the new one , also it said you suppose to have 180 but the remaining is 0 after rest time i get 180 back then after one request api i got 139 after another request i got 60 as remain